# Why am I getting 500 response code on passing wrong email or password to service in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I have been running into a very strange problem. I am trying to implement log in service in my app. When I pass right email and password service returns response as expected(means no error comes) but when I delibrately pass wrong email or password geInputStream() method throws FileNotFoundException. I don't know what is the reason behind this.Further more, before calling getInputStream() method i checked status code as well(this is the case when I am passing wrong email and password intentionally).The status code was 500. I checked for 500 and that was internal server error. My question is why is that so? I mean when intentionally passing wrong email or password why internal server occurred? One more thing I would like to mention that I have checked the same service on post man it is working fine as expected. If i pass wrong email or password postman returns the expected error. Below is the code I am using

```
  private String invokeWebservice() {
    String data = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        String webservice = Constants.BASE_URL + serviceName;
        LogUtility.debugLog("webservice just called "+ webservice);
        URL url = new URL(webservice);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        if (isPost) {
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            if (jsonObject != null)
                writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
            writer.close();
        }

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(l + nl);
        in.close();

        data = sb.toString();

        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtility.errorLog("exception while calling web service");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // LogUtility.errorLogWithException(ex, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: This error mostly comes due to lack of validations at the server end. I would suggest checking server (service) end code.

Comment: No i don't think this can be server side error because as i mentioned on post man it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time now I was able to solve my problem.Posting my answer for others. Passing wrong email and password to the service was right and server was consuming those parameters as well and because there was an error(because email and password) that is why it was returning 500 code. So, I checked for status code if it was 200 then I used getInputStream() method and else i called getErrorStream() method. By this way i got the stream that has property for error(this property contains error detail). Below is the code i used

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
        } else {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        }
```

Hope it helps other as well.